# Calculate how much to Pan/Tilt image

Tags: c#, image, image-processing

I am currently implementing Pan/Tilt/Zoom support in my application. I pass in an image and then calculate zoom in the following manner

```
int widthPercent = width / 100;
int heightPercent = height / 100;

int zoomX = width - (widthPercent * (int)Zoom);
int zoomY = height - (heightPercent * (int)Zoom);
```

where width is width of original image, height is height of original image and Zoom is a value passed in from the UI, ranging from 0 to 100.

I now wish to implement Pan/Tilt support while an image is zoomed in so that the whole image can still be accessed. Again Pan and Tilt will be controlled from the UI(again 0 to 100) but I want it to stay within the boundaries of the image so that the image does not repeat which it is currently doing.

I am current calculating the Pan and Tilt like so:

```
// Calculate Pan
int panWidthPercent = width / 100;
int finalPan = (int)Pan * panWidthPercent;

// Calculate Tilt
int tiltHeightPercent = height / 100;
int finalTilt = (int)Tilt * tiltHeightPercent;
```

This works to an extent however it seems to keep repeating the image after panning for a small time(usually when Pan = 10 or more). I wish it to stop after it renders all the image i.e it reaches the width but adding something like the following doesnt seem to stop this

```
if(finalPan >= width) finalPan = width;
```

Once the values are calculate I create a source rectangle using these values

```
mClippingRectangle = new Int32Rect(finalPan, finalTilt, zoomX, zoomY);
```

which is then used against the base image for rendering only that rectangle

In short how can I calculate how much I should pan/tilt when I already know the zoom of the image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to accomplish it by checking whether the Pan/Tilt Amount added to the zoom width/height is greater than the overall image width/height then stop it from panning/tilting

```
// Calculate Pan
double finalPan = Pan * widthPercent;
if ((finalPan + zoomX) >= width)
{
    finalPan = width - zoomX;
}

// Calculate Tilt
double finalTilt = Tilt * heightPercent;
if ((finalTilt + zoomY) >= height)
{
    finalTilt = height - zoomY;
}
```